# Neither Android nor iPad respect viewport at all

Tags: css, ipad, web-applications, android-layout, mobile

Every single site says to use the settings in viewport but they flat out, simply do not work at all under any conditions no matter how perfect.

This code does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Hello Android</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello iPad
</body>
</html>
```

You can change any of the settings and it doesn't work. It does absolutely nothing.

You can't really get more stripped down code than that so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: dont know anything about viewport but are you sure it shouldnt have any caps?

Comment: my guess is that since this tag is not part of the standard and you're using XHTML doctype, the tag is invalid in standard XHTML. Also, try using Firefox Mobile, which [claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) that it does support the tag.

Comment: the code is right. it's an exact match with jqm code and android documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

Comment: so fyi, I still have not found the answer to this. If anyone has an idea let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just answering my own question to help anyone who might stumble upon this after a google search.

The problem was the content was getting returned inside of an iFrame which pwned the viewport. Took out the iFrame and problem solved.